# Display incoming messages in different html page

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This is piece of code for small chat.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

and html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

on console window I see received messages from client but what i want to achieve is when i open http://localhost:3000/msgmonitor i would like to see all this messages that are comming from clients. How to do this?

Comment: So, you basically want to dynamically modify the view (front page of your site aka HTML) when you receive new messages ? React/Angular should do the trick if you want to spend enough time to learn them but in return it will be way much easyer for you to code that kind of thing, or you can use ajax which could be a good alternative for something that simple.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what is the better way. I had just started to learn those things. My idea is to have two files. One is index.hr that will display page where user can enter message and another one is msgmonitor.html where will be displayed all messages in realtime that are comming from users. There is no any kind of database where are messages are stored. Let's sad that I want to see everything that now I see in console window when i run node server.js

Comment: I'am sorry, but the client who send the message, the browser from which  user, let say, "anon90" sent "hello world" is the ONLY client who currently have the message. I see only one way to do that without a database: write each message you receive on your server directly into an html file which means the more messages you get, the bigger the file, i'am sorry, but this is beyond dumb. Not only would it be a cleaner way to just store them in a DB, it will also be, in my opinion, way much easyer than rewriting a file every single time you receive a message.

Comment: Maybe there is some misunderstanding. If you run this sample that i put you will see some outputs in the console. When message arrives from client you can see in ouput this message. I would like to have this output displayed in browser. Like some kind of monitor of connected clients and received messages.

Comment: I don't think i misunderstood your problem, the fact is, as much as i understood your post: you are not storing anything. Starting from this point, what you are currently doing is just displaying messages you received in your console, which does not need any kind of storage. In a web browser, you are using HTML to display those messages, which means you have to rebuild your .html from scratch each time you receive a message in order to add a div and the text you received to your display as it won't do it by itself.

Comment: If you don't care about old message but just want to show to the user message received since he opened the page, then you don't need any storage at all you could just send them by the web and Use Angular/React/Ajax to update your display on the run, but if you want to show the user new message and older one received before he opened  your website you'll need a place to store those. I was just trying to bring those two points up :)

Comment: No I don't need to show older messages, just current messages that arrives in moment when is opened http://localhost:3000/msgmonitor